# Google App Engine - I have to restart the development server anytime I make changes to a servlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have to restart the development server anytime I make changes to a servlet. Is there a way I can make it so I don't have to do this?  Restarting the dev app server takes about 20 seconds for my project.

Comment: Are you using any of the IDE plugins? (e.g. Netbeans, Eclipse, etc.)

Comment: @catchwa I was using the netbeans plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the netbeans plugin, and once I moved over to using the Eclipse plugin, I no longer had to restart the server every change.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Hot deployment is not supported as of now.

Comment: I haven't used Google App Engine, but would hot *swapping* work?  Clearly not a panacaea, as you can't make any schema changes, but maybe better than nothing.

Comment: @Kirk What do you mean by hot swapping? If I replace the *.class files in my build dir there is no change, is that what you mean?