# Google Cloud: dev_appserver.py doesn't reflect live changes

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, dev-appserver

I'm developing a web app to deploy on Google Cloud's App Engine. When I make some changes `dev_appserver.py` sees them (console says `Detected file changes`) but those change don't go live, i.e. even if I refresh the page I still see the old code. For the new code to be visible I need to kill the process and restart `dev_appserver.py`.

Is there any way around this?

My `app.yalm` file:

```
runtime: python37
```

I'm developing the app using Flask.

Comment: Seems like this question has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508637/app-engine-development-server-does-not-reload-code-when-changed

Answer (score -1):

That's working as intended. Your app is "uploaded" and "deployed" to the Cloud and the local dev environment emulates that. You can't simply make changes in your code and expect it to be live. You need to redeploy; in this case, rerun the dev_appserver.py.

There are [hacky ways of forcing it to reload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5258066/4092401) (or you could just rerun the deploy command). Some users have tried [Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3688315/4092401) and it apparently allows you perform hot updates during development.

Comment: Not true, the dev_appserver does try to hot reload code, but doesn't always succeed.

```
INFO     2020-03-28 15:23:00,130 module.py:432] [api] Detected file changes:
  /home/user/code/bikebuds/gae/api/4913
  /home/user/code/bikebuds/gae/api/bikebuds.py
```